# How to get an integer value from Entry in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been trying to make a simple program to compare three numbers. I just used the START and STOP buttons for the sake of using Tkinter but now I wanted to insert some Entry Boxes to input data instead of the simple IDLE.

Every time I try to fix it I get the same ValueError

I've tried using IntVar, taking multiple variables and stuff, but I couldn't get to a conclusion. I also wouldn't like to use IntVar because my teacher's going to be mad if I use it and I don't know why =P

---

```
t1 = tk.Entry(root)

t1.grid(row = 8, column = 0)

t2 = tk.Entry(root)

t2.grid(row = 10, column = 0)

t3 = tk.Entry(root)

t3.grid(row = 12, column = 0)


x = int(t1.get())

y = int(t2.get())

z = int(t3.get())
```

---

ERROR:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/CB
>   Singh/Desktop/Compare01.py", line 25, in 
>       x = int(t1.get()) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: There is nothing in the entry widget when you try to convert them to a `int`, thus the error.

Comment: `Entry()` doesn't work like `input()` - it doesn't wait for user's data so using `t1.get()` directly after `t1 = tk.Entry()` is useless. It will try to get value from `Entry` when you start program - even before you see window. Use `Button` to run function which will use `t1.get()` to get data.  Of course user can put chars on `Entry`  and you should also use `try/except` with `int()` to catch it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
text1=tk.IntVar()
t1 = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=text1)
t2 = t1.get()
```

Comment: I don't think that quite is what the OP is looking for. While literally correct, calling `t1.get()` immediately after creating the widget will just return the default value, not a value input by the user.

Comment: You can use a button to take the value input by the user and update it

Comment: Yes, but that isn't part of your answer. Remember: you're answering a question for someone with very limited understanding of tkinter.